# (Handlebars/JSON) nested each to read array

Tags: json, node.js, handlebars.js

I've a `family`-table, with property `member` as array.

The first `#each` works fine, but I can't make the second/nested `#each` work to read data from the array within `family`-table (see JSON part).

I tried these 2 ways without success:

```
  {{#each family}}                   |      {{#each family as |x|}}
    <h1>{{surName}}</h1>             |         <h1>{{x.surName}}</h1>
                                     |
    {{#each member}}                 |         {{#each x.member as |y|}}
       <h1>{{firstName}}</h1>        |            <h1>{{y.firstName}}</h1>
    {{else}}                         |         {{else}}
       <h1>Not working</h1>          |            <h1>Not working</h1>
    {{/each}}                        |         {{/each}} 
                                     |
  {{else}}                           |       {{else}}
      <h1>No family</h1>             |           <h1>No family</h1>
  {{/each}}                          |       {{/each}}
```

JSON:

```
//family collection
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a6a906492b7b30014b18111"
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2018-01-26T02:20:20.428Z"
    },
    "surName": "x",
    "members": [
        {
            "firstName": "x"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "y"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Route:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const router = express.Router();

    require("../models/Family");
    const Family = mongoose.model("family");

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        Family.find({}) 
        .sort({ date: 'desc' })
        .then(family => {
          res.render('family/index', {
            family: family
          });
        });
    });    
module.exports = router;
```

EDIT:

My Family.js Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const FamilySchema = new Schema({
  surName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

mongoose.model('family', FamilySchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two place you need to change

1. Your family collection needs to be an `array` instead of an `object`
2. The data filed is `members` instead of `member`

The following code works

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const family = [{
      "_id": {
          "$oid": "5a6a906492b7b30014b18111"
      },
      "date": {
          "$date": "2018-01-26T02:20:20.428Z"
      },
      "surName": "x",
      "members": [
          {
              "firstName": "x"
          },
          {
              "firstName": "y"
          },
          {
              "firstName": "z"
          }
      ]
  }]

    res.render('home', {
      family
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

home.handlebars

```
{{#each family as |family|}}                  
    <h1>{{family.surName}}</h1>           

    {{#each family.members as |member|}}                
       <h1>{{member.firstName}}</h1>       
    {{else}}                        
       <h1>Not working</h1>         
    {{/each}}                        

  {{else}}                          
      <h1>No family</h1>             
{{/each}}
```

Comment: "Your family collection need to be an array instead of an object" - how do I do that exactly? I'm using mongoDB which I uploaded to mLab.

Comment: You can try the toArray API in your Document Find Promise chain `collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)
    callback(docs);
  });`

Comment: I get `TypeError: Family.find(...).toArray is not a function`. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: What is the type of  `Family`. You can check the documentation here https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Comment: it's the collection name, just like in my route code.

Comment: Are you using mongoose? If it is, you can not use toArray because this function is only exists while you are using MangoDB native cursor. You can do data transformation in your then callback like `Family.find(...).then(family => { const familyArray = []; familyArray.append(family); res.render('home', {family: familyArray})})`

Comment: I'm getting `familyArray.append is not a function at Family.find.then.family`.

Comment: I added the whole code from route part in my question.

Comment: use familyArray.push. This is basic array api. I mixed it with Swift

Comment: How do I use familyArray.push? I just started to learn node.js

Comment: That's fine. Just same. `familyArray.push(family)`. Check detail https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp.

Comment: .. I forgot to mention my model.. I don't have members property inside it. Is that maybe why I can't get members part? Sorry I totally forgot about that part. - I added it in my question.

Comment: If there is no members, the handlebars part will not render it. But you should separate the concerns first. I think using a mocked JSON to make this rendering part work is fair enough for your question. And I think my code works for your use-case. Hope it helps you. If that's fine please accept my answer thanks

Comment: I see. Can you update your solution to use the .push part? I don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: Worked now. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I can help you